# column fields Join in Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like below :

**Table1** :

```
teamid  teamname
 1      AAA
 2      BBB
 3      CCC
```

**Table2**:

```
id  team1   team2
1    1       2
2    2       3          
3    1       3
```

Table 2 contain two fields **team1** and **team2** that reference to table1 **teamid**.

Expected Result :

```
id  team1   team2   
1    AAA     BBB
2    BBB     CCC
3    AAA     CCC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join `table1` 2 times as

```
select 
t2.id,
t1.teamname as team1,
t11.teamname as team2
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t1.teamid = t2.team1
join table1 t11 on t11.teamid = t2.team2
```

Comment: Thanks @abhik. one more question suppose i have third table like this and i want join third table in query is it possible?

Comment: Yes its possible. Update the question and add the details with desired output.